# java.io.PrintStream getting blocked in linux systems

Tags: java, linux, selenium-webdriver

```
"Exec Stream Pumper" daemon prio=5 id=126 state=BLOCKED
LockOwnerName= pool-1-thread-9 LockOwnerId=129 LockName=java.io.PrintStream@27c7422a
BlockedTime= -1 BlockedCount= 1
     at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:447)
     at org.openqa.selenium.io.MultiOutputStream.write(MultiOutputStream.java:40)
     at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
     at org.apache.commons.exec.StreamPumper.run(StreamPumper.java:108)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

```
"Forwarding quit on session ea6c16f7-a829-4711-a058-e0cae7f49447 to remote"  prio=5 id=122 state=BLOCKED
LockOwnerName= pool-1-thread-9 LockOwnerId=129 LockName=java.io.PrintStream@27c7422a
BlockedTime= -1 BlockedCount= 10
     at java.io.PrintStream.flush(PrintStream.java:337)
     at org.openqa.selenium.io.MultiOutputStream.flush(MultiOutputStream.java:48)
     at org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler.stop(PumpStreamHandler.java:195)
     at org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess.destroy(OsProcess.java:135)
     at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:139)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.stop(DriverService.java:281)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:129)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:541)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:596)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:443)
     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.quit(FirefoxDriver.java:307)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.lambda$new$1(EventFiringWebDriver.java:106)
     at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$$Lambda$315/1342232709.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.quit(Unknown Source)
     at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.quit(EventFiringWebDriver.java:212)
```

I am trying to run Selenium java application in linux machine, after few runs, the process getting hanged. On checking the thread dump found java.io.PrintStream is blocking the process. The same applications works fine in windows.

I have tried restarting the process after few runs and it worked. Is there any way to address this issue

Comment: Are you running this as a sub-process of another Java app? If so, show details.

Comment: Yes I'm running this process as a separate process (Separate JVM) septate from Main Java application and using socket to make communications between the processes.

Comment: Sub-process is different to separate process, which do you mean? If sub-process, the error is probably in the Java  launching app.